# in this case - what is better has many or has many through?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

i have a dish recipe it has many groceries

```
class Dish < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :groceries
```

i am cosidering - should I make it simple like the example above but have, say,
100 dishes and each one has tomatoes, carrots, cucambers - 
so the groceries table will be big 
with the same groceries OR should I use has many through and make a groceries table 
and then make a join to connect dishes and groceries so the grocery table is small , say 
only tomatoes carrots and cucambers, but the join table will be big to connect all the dishes and groceries.

if it does not matter i prefer the first - its alot more simple to program...

Answer (score 6):

The advantage of "has many through" is twofold...

first, since the grocery items are table driven you minimize spelling errors and vagaries in recipes (where for example one recipe has "tomatos" and another recipe has "tomatoes")

second, if you make it has many through you can make it a two-way relationship, so you can do...

```
carrots = Grocery.find_by(name: "carrots")

carrots.recipes # show all the recipes using carrots
```

Answer (score 0):

**Many-to-Many**

You'll generally want to use a [`many-to-many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) join in Rails for something like this, as unless you're actually *creating* `groceries` with each `dish`, it will be very inefficient & "WET"

The way, in my opinion, to associate the two types of data is to use a join model - there are two ways to do this:

- [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)
- [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Depending on how your system needs to work, `has_many :through` might be slightly more work than `has_and_belongs_to_many`; its benefits being that you can append lots of different data to each join record, whilst `has_and_belongs_to_many` only associates two types of record

---

**has_and_belongs_to_many**

If you don't have to add any specific details for the join table, you'll want to use `has_and_belongs_to_many`:

```
#app/models/dish.rb
Class Dish < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :groceries
end

#app/models/grocery.rb
Class Grocery < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :dishes
end
```

This will allow you to create the following table:

```
#dishes_groceries
dish_id | grocery_id
```

Consequently allowing you to call the following:

```
@dish = Dish.find params[:id]
@dish.grocies.each do |grocery|
   grocery.name #-> "Carrot"
end
```

--

**has_many :through**

If you wanted to use `has_many :through`, you'll have to make a separate model, which will allow you to include other attributes (as its accompanying table will have a primary_key):

```
#app/models/dish.rb
Class Dish < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :dish_groceries
   has_many :groceries, through: :dish_groceries
end

#app/models/dish_grocery.rb
Class DishGrocery < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :dish
   belongs_to :grocery
end

#app/models/grocery.rb
Class Grocery < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :dish_groceries
   has_many :dishes, through: :dish_groceries
end
```